# How a nonce from proof of work ensures valid transaction records in block?

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency

I am new to Blockchain, learning to implement it in javascript while understanding things. I have one question that I tried to search a lot, didn't get any clear explanation.

**Question** : Lets suppose I have 3 transaction records and previous block hash. I also found out the Nonce value. Combined I got desired hash of 4 '0's at front. Now everywhere I read, it says this proves the validity of block. But How?! I mean, What if before finding hash, I (or someone) TAMPER WITH THOSE 3 TRANSACTIONS. I could again find a hash with 4 '0's but this time I altered AMOUNT in those 3 transactions (making them faulty).

How can we be sure that those transaction amounts are LEGIT. Consider this is the newest block, I am concerned about validity of those 3 transaction records.

If proof of work doesn't guarantees the critical information (transaction records) then what is the point of it. What thing validates those transaction records in block are not faulty? (The miners haven't tampered with them, before adding block to blockchain)

The proof of work & hash block functions in JS :

```js
// Hashing Single Block
Blockchain.prototype.hashBlock = function(previousBlockHash, currentBlockData, nonce){
  const dataAsString = previousBlockHash + 
                       nonce.toString() + 
                       JSON.stringify(currentBlockData);
  const hash = sha256(dataAsString);
  return hash;
};

// Proof of Work
Blockchain.prototype.proofOfWork = function(previousBlockHash, currentBlockData){
  let nonce = 0;
  let hash = this.hashBlock(previousBlockHash, currentBlockData, nonce);
  while(hash.substr(0, 4) !== '0000'){
    nonce++;
    hash = this.hashBlock(previousBlockHash, currentBlockData, nonce);
    // console.log(hash);
  }
  return nonce;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to try to give a simplified answer, as there are many details that are not required to understand the solution.

First of all, let's look at what a transaction consists of:

1. The transaction data:

- the address the money comes from
- the address the money is going to
- the amount

2. a signature of the transaction data created with your private key
3. your public key

When you create an address for people to transfer money to, where is this address coming from? First of all, you create a public/private key pair. A public/private key pair is the result of [some complicated mathematics](https://sectigo.com/public-key-vs-private-key). What you can do with these keys is interesting. You can sign a message with your private key. If your friend has your public key, they can verify that the signature is valid for that message, which means that they can verify that it was you writing that message.

In blockchain, an address is the sha256 hash of a public key.

Now when it is time to transfer your money, you need to do two things:

1. Show that you are the owner of that address. You do that by providing the public key. The miners in this case can hash your public key to verify that it results in the 'from' address.
2. Confirm that you own the private key. You do that by creating the signature of the transaction data.

If a miner changes the 'to' address, the 'from' address, or the amount, the signature of the transaction data isn't valid anymore.

If a miner decides to add a new signature based on the changed data, it won't verify anymore with the public key in the transaction.

If the miner decides to change both the signature and the public so they match, then the 'from' address won't be correct anymore as it is the hash of the public key.

I left out some details like:

- A 'from' address refers to a previous transaction
- The amount in the previous transaction needs to be spend completely. So if there is too much in there, you will have a second 'to' address which is in your control, basically transferring the rest back to yourself
- There can be many 'from' addresses and 'to' addresses in one transaction. Each 'from' address requires a public key and signature.
- The transaction actually contains a script that says how to verify the addresses and signatures. If you expand the language used in that script, then you are talking about a smart contract.
- There are private keys which can generate multiple public keys, and therefore multiple address, so you don't have to manage multiple private keys.
- There is no way to verify if a 'to' address is valid. So you can transfer money to an address where nobody has the private key for.

You can find the complicated details of what goes into a transaction here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction

Comment: That was really great explanation, i think all the puzzle pieces I had now fits after addition of your answer :)

Comment: This is a reaaaally great explanation! It deserves hundreds of upvotes!

Answer (score 1):

The transaction record itself is digitally signed by the party which created the transaction in the first place. Only he/she has the private key to generate the transaction. When you change one value in the transaction record, the digital signature becomes invalid and therefore the transaction itself becomes invalid. You can change the transaction record data, but then no other node will accept this transaction (or the mined block) as it contains invalid data.

This check if a transaction record itself is valid or not is unrelated to the proof of work you have to do to mine a new block.

Comment: Thanks mate, question : how does other nodes check digital signature of transaction is valid or not?

Comment: @krupeshAnadkat That depends on the implementation and specification of the blockchain/transaction.

Comment: How it is done in case of Bitcoin blockchain, how nodes (physical computers in network I believe) verifies digital signature of those transactions?

Comment: @krupeshAnadkat You can read https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OP_CHECKSIG on how the bitcoin script engine is used to verify that the signature of a transaction is valid.

Comment: Thank you :)  I was confused about this since long.